# How do I solve $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac {\ln(x-1)^2}{x} $?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I just can't get past the $x-1$. The $2$ I know how to get rid of.

$$\lim_{x\to +∞}\frac {\ln\left((x-1)^2\right)}{x}  $$

Comment: Are you aware of L'Hospital's Rule?

Comment: is the numerator $\ln^2(x-1)$ or $\ln ((x-1)^2)$?

Comment: $$= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(x)^2}{x + 1} = ...$$

Comment: Let $u=x-1.$ then $u\rightarrow\infty.$

Comment: It's the second one, like I put it... I don't think I'm familiar with that rule, haven't learnt it yet.

Comment: $\lim_{x \rightarrow + \infty} \dfrac{\ln((x-1)^2)}{x}=\lim_{x \rightarrow + \infty} \dfrac{2 \ln(x-1)}{x}=0$ since the logarithm grows asymptotically slower than the polynomial.

Comment: That cannot be solved without L'Hôspital. You may copy it wrong.

Comment: @TheodorosMpalis The function itself was just f(x) = ln (x-1)^2 , I didn't copy wrong, just divided by x to find the m for the oblique asymptote, but thank you anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\ln(x-1)^2}{x}$$

It is not hard to show $\ln x< x$

$\ln(x-1)^2=4\ln\sqrt{x-1}\leq 4\sqrt{x-1}\leq 4\sqrt x$

So the limit is smaller than

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{4\sqrt{x}}{x}=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac 4{\sqrt x}=0$$

Now the following is true because square root must be non negative

$-4\sqrt x\leq ln(x-1)^2$

So the limit is bounded by $0$

Answer (score 1):

Use *equivalents*:

$(x-1)^2\sim_\infty x^2$ and none of them approach $1$ in a neighbourhood of $+\infty$, hence $\;\ln(x-1)^2\sim_\infty \ln x^2=2\ln x\;$ and finally
$$\frac{\ln(x-1)^2}{x}\sim_\infty2\,\frac{\ln x}x \to 0.$$

*Note:* In general equivalence of functions is not compatible with composition on the left with another function.

Comment: You probably should be careful introducing this notation to a beginner.  For instance $\exp((x-1)^2)$ is **not** asymptotic to $\exp(x^2)$, but that won't be at all clear to OP.

Comment: @Erick Wong: You're right. I've  added a short caveat.

Answer (score -1):

By applying [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) you have: 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} (\ln(x-1)^2)'=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{2}{x-1}=0$$
and $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(x)'=1$$
Therefore the limit $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{(\ln(x-1)^2)'}{x'}=\frac{0}{1}=0$$
exists and it is equal to
$$\lim_{x\to +∞}\frac {ln(x-1)^2}{x}$$

Comment: She said she hasn't learned L'Hôspital yet

Comment: @TheodorosMpalis Well, it's a good time to look at it then..

Comment: I understand that principle, it's easy to comprehend, we use derivatives... I'm just not suposed to use it yet..

Comment: @Tatiana So, was this given as an exercise that you are supposed to solve without L'Hospital?

Comment: Yes I mean, since I haven't learned that yet...
The exercise was to find asymptotes for f(x)= ln(x-1)^2 , so to find the oblique asymptote I did the limit of the function divided by x to find the m... That's what got me to that expression....

Comment: @Tatiana I see..Well, check Bububu's answer then. I hope that when you do study L'Hospital's, you will find this more usefull!

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake Thank you anyway!